# SharePoint 2016 on premise integration with Lync or Skype for business

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, lync

Is there any chat solution available for SharePoint 2016 on premise? I believe Lync was used for this purpose but its last version was Lync 2013 which I am not sure if supported by SharePoint 2016.

Is there on presmise version of Skype for business available which can be integrated with SharePoint 2016?

Main idea is to use for messaging and chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lync 2013 should supported by SharePoint 2016 currently.

You can also install Skype for business 2016 from the following articles:

http://lyncdude.com/2015/09/24/skype-for-business-standalone-client-and-office-2016/index.html

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1196587-skype-for-business-2016-where-can-i-download

Answer (score 2):

I think [Microsoft Teams](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/microsoft-teams-in-nutshell/) can match your requirements!

**[Microsoft Teams](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/microsoft-teams-in-nutshell/)** can

- Integrate with SharePoint,
- Install on Windows and Linux.
- Provide Chat functionality and more features.

**BTW,** Microsoft announced,

> Skype for Business online will be retired on July 31, 2021, and after
>   that date, the service will no longer be accessible!! The frankly alternative solution is **[Microsoft Teams](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/microsoft-teams-in-nutshell/)**.

**For more details,** please check [Microsoft Teams in a nutshell](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/microsoft-teams-in-nutshell/)

Comment: Teams does not integrate with SharePoint Server 2016.

Comment: And Microsoft Teams look like cloud based solution. I am only looking for on premise solution.